# Regex -replace in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to read a `.sln` file and extract the strings that contain the path to the `.csproj` within my solution.

The lines that contain the information that I am looking for look like this:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project", "Project\Project.csproj", "{0DB516E6-4358-499D-BFBF-408F50A44E14}"
```

So, this is what I am trying:

```
$projectsInFile = Select-String "$slnFile" -pattern '^Project'
$csprojectsNames = $projectsInFile -replace ".+= `"(\S*) `""
```

Now, `$csprojectsName` contain the information that I am looking for, but also the rest of the string.

Just like this:

```
Project\Project.csproj", "{0DB516E6-4358-499D-BFBF-408F50A44E14}"
```

What is the best way to retrieve the name of the `.csproj` file without needing to manually cut the rest of the string?

Thank you

Comment: `$projectsInFile -replace '.+= "(\S*) "(.*?)",.*"','$2'` working on cleaner ways. Put the part you want to keep in a group. Eat up the whole string and just replace it with the second group which has the string you want. Could also consider splitting on commas.... but that would only be useful if the structure was the same

Comment: Thanks. But, what I need is the "Project\Project.csproj" section. No the project

Comment: Check it again. I used the wrong number in the replacement it was fixed about a minute ago in an edit. Sorry

Comment: Thanks. If you want post the answer and I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is capture the entire string and use a capture group in your replacement string thereby dropping the unneeded parts.

```
$csprojectsNames = $projectsInFile -replace '.+= "(\S*) "(.*?)",.*"','$2'
```

The second capture group is the data inbetween the quotes that follow `= "Project", "....."`. Since it is the second capture group we replace the entire with that group `'$2'`. Using single quotes ensure that PowerShell does not try to expand a variable.

**Better approach**

You might just be able to use `[^"]*?\.csproj` in `select-string` directly without having to do a secondary parse. That will match everything before .csproj that is not a quote so it wont gooble up too much.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the details and improved answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group to capture the file path and then use the value of the group in as the replacement value.  For instance:

```
$csprojectsNames = $projectsInFile -replace 'Project\(.*?\) = "Project", "(.*?)"', '$1'
```